# Alternativa money_format em php em windows

Tags: php

Ao usar o money_format em windows, a função não funciona, porque a função só é compatível com sistemas strfmon.

```
$number = 1234.56;

setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_US');
echo money_format('%i', $number) . "\n";
// USD 1,234.56
```

O código em cima, funciona em ambiente MAC e Linux, mas não em windows. Que alternativa posso arranjar?

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com [este post do SO em inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6369887/alternative-to-money-format-function-in-php-on-windows-platform), você pode utilizar a [Intl extension](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.intl.php). Por exemplo:

```
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'de_DE', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
echo $fmt->formatCurrency(1234567.891234567890000, "EUR")."\n";
echo $fmt->formatCurrency(1234567.891234567890000, "RUR")."\n";
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'ru_RU', NumberFormatter::CURRENCY );
echo $fmt->formatCurrency(1234567.891234567890000, "EUR")."\n";
echo $fmt->formatCurrency(1234567.891234567890000, "RUR")."\n";
```

**Saída:**

```
1.234.567,89 €
1.234.567,89 RUR
1 234 567,89€
1 234 567,89р.
```